# How do I use java 8's stream collect from scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, generics

I have this piece of code:

```
import java.util.stream._
import java.util.function._

final case class AbcTest(value: String)

def funToFunction[InT, OutT](fun: InT => OutT): Function[InT, OutT] = new Function[InT, OutT] {
  override def apply(t: InT): OutT = fun(t)
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  Stream.of("a", "b", "c")
    .map[AbcTest](funToFunction((v: String) => AbcTest(v)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

And it fails with this error message:

```
    Error:(43, 27) type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.stream.Collector[Nothing,?0(in method main),java.util.List[Nothing]] where type ?0(in method main)
 required: java.util.stream.Collector[_ >: test.AbcTest, ?, ?]
Note: Nothing <: Any, but Java-defined trait Collector is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
      .collect(Collectors.toList)
```

I don't understand what's happening, please help.

Comment: I'm not yet clear on "why" but `Stream.of("a", "b", "c").map[AbcTest](funToFunction((v: String)=>AbcTest(v))` seems to work. Type inference seems to be the problem.

Comment: @GPI was testing this, and in my compiler, it says this is missing a ')', and when I add it, I get the same issue... Different behavior for you?

Comment: @jwismar please retry, it's because I removed `java.util.function` from `java.util.function.Function`. I updated the answer.

Comment: @GPI Yup that made the difference. Seems to work now.

Comment: Can you guys tell me how to make collect(Collectors.toList()) work with this? There's also a type inference problem.

Comment: I will update the answer to ask about collect.

Comment: the scala-java8-compat library is useful for converting between Scala's function types and Java's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... from what I have seen the following works absolutely fine, remember to just help a little in some type inferencing

```
import java.util.{stream => jStream}
import java.util.{function => jFunction}

def funToFunction[InT, OutT](fun: InT => OutT): jFunction.Function[InT, OutT] =
  new jFunction.Function[InT, OutT] {
    override def apply(t: InT): OutT = fun(t)
  }

final case class AbcTest(value: String)

val javaList =
  jStream.Stream.of("a", "b")
    .map[AbcTest](funToFunction((s: String) => AbcTest(s)))
    .collect(jStream.Collectors.toList[AbcTest])
```