# How to perform a `Collectors.toList()` correspondingly in scala

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming, collectors, partialfunction

I have the following class and method used in the code below with `ids` being a `Set[String]`:

```
case class PAV ()

def aggregate(pId: String, iId: Option[String], count: Int): PAV
```

I have tried the following:

One, using `java.util.stream.Collectors`

```
tuple._2.get.ids.toStream
  .map(i => aggregate("some", Option(i), tuple._1.data.`type`))
  .collect(Collectors.toList[PAV]) // required PartialFunction found Function0
```

Two, using `identity`

```
tuple._2.get.ids.toStream
  .map(i => aggregate("some", Option(i), tuple._1.data.`type`))
  .collect(identity(PAV)) // required PartialFunction found PAV.type
```

I have tried the above based on [How do I use java 8's stream collect from scala 2.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255632/how-do-i-use-java-8s-stream-collect-from-scala-2-11)

Curious to know, why not provide a `Function` to `collect`?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a java.util.stream, and not scala.collection.immutable.stream? The collect-method on Scala Stream takes a partial function as parameter. https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html

Comment: If you're using scala streams, you can simply use `stream.toList()` to collect all elements into a list.

Comment: I do not understand, you want to call `Collectors.toList`? Or want a similar behavior? Or are you asking why we have a function also called collect with has a completely different functionality?

Comment: @marstran Yes, I am sure about the import.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez either works for me as of now, I am finally looking for a `List[PAV]`

Comment: @Naman And what is the type of `tuple._2.get.iIds`?

Comment: Regardless of what you imported, `Set.toStream` returns a `scala.collection.immutable.Stream`, not a `java.util.stream.Stream`. `collect` is a function that is overriden from scala's `TraversableLike`, and has a completely different meaning than java.util.stream.Stream's `collect()`.

Comment: @sachav  Yeah, that works. Thanks.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez As stated in the question *`ids` being a `Set[String]`*

Comment: @Naman `tuple._2.get.ids.map(...).toList` I would recommend you to check the [**scaldoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) and study a little bit of **Sclaa** before using it.

Comment: @sachav With some background of Java, I had intended to the thought of using something like `.collect(Collector.toList())` and that's where I faltered I believe. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Please, please, please can people put answers in answers, not comments?

Comment: @sachav I agree with Tim, though I understand that the manual/documentation could have helped me understand the existing capability. But I couldn't really find an answer to lookup for that on StackOverflow. I would, therefore, suggest to either mark this as duplicate if appropriate or make an answer for future readers that might get some help.